# Android: Theme is not working for actionbar in splitActionBarWhenNarrow

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am having a activity with splitActionBarWhenNarrow as uioption declared in Manifest file, as a result I am getting the action bar menu items as a footer..

Because of the split I am getting a problem in portrait mode. I had set the theme for the Action bar as below

```
-<style parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse" name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar">

<item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/header_bg</item>

<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ProjActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

<item name="background">@drawable/header_bg</item>

<item name="android:background">@drawable/header_bg</item>

<item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/header_bg</item>

<item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/header_bg</item>

</style>
```

Where header_bg is the drawable image with red background

[image]  [image]

If u see my image you could find my problem as in portrait mode I am getting the action bar in blue color, which I need to make red. The same theme works fine in landscape mode as the action bar is red in color

Note: The action item is my customized action bar created using Actionmode.Callback

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a style for `ActionMode`, here's an example:

```
<style name="Your.ActionMode" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionMode">
    <item name="android:background">your_background</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">your_split_background</item>
</style>
```

To apply the theme, create a new `item` for `android:actionModeStyle` in your root theme.